# Existence of skeletons in ZFC

Tags: ct.category-theory, set-theory, foundations

Influenced [by this question from a fellow lagomorph](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/385472/global-choice-and-skeletons-of-large-categories?), I would like to get to the bottom of existence of a skeleton of a category. I want to stay in ZFC, so I do not assume the global axiom of choice. Hence, not all categories necessarily have a skeleton.

Suppose $C$ is a category, $S$ is its skeleton, i.e., a full subcategory that meets every isomorphism class in a single object. I understand that the existence of $S$ is assured, if $C$ is accessible category.

**Question 1:** Are there any other, weaker or unrelated conditions that ensure existence of $S$?

**Question 2:** What would be a good example of $C$ such that $S$ does not exist?

Now the embedding $i:S\rightarrow C$ is not necessarily an equivalence. The issue is the same: we have to construct the (quasi)-inverse functor $f:C\rightarrow S$, both on objects and morphisms. To do that for each object $X\in C$ we need to choose $Y\in S$ and an isomorphism $X{\cong}Y$ -- using the global choice twice. Again $C$ being accessible gets us through.

**Question 3:** Are there any other, weaker or unrelated conditions that ensure existence $f$, once we know that $S$ exists?

**Question 4:** What would be a good example of $C$ such that $S$ exists but $f$ does not?

Comment: Are your categories classes or sets? If classes, are they definable?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: for small categories (the objects form a set) the existence of a skeleton is just a single application of the axiom of choice, so I think it's safe to assume we're dealing with large categories. The question then is under what conditions we can avoid using global choice.

Comment: Why do we need to worry about the inverse functor $f : C \to S$? The definition of a skeleton that you gave does not involve any such quasi-inverse. Perhaps you meant to say: A skeleton of $C$ is a skeletal category $S$ which is equivalent to $C$. (A category is skeletal if all isomorphisms are identities.) With this definition, we do indeed have to exhibit an equivalence. Alternatively, we may ask for a functor $S \to C$ which is full and faithful and essentially surjective on objects.

Comment: The categories are classes, indeed.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but it's worth mentioning: Scott's trick shows that in ZF every category has a 'weak skeleton,' i.e., a full subcategory whose inclusion is essentially surjective and in which every isomorphism class is a set (instead of possibly a proper class). (In some sense this *is* Scott's trick, although it's normally phrased in terms of just equivalence relations.)

Comment: @Andrej Bauer Not sure but I am used to having a pair of quasi-inverse functors. This makes me feel safe. If we just have $S\rightarrow C$ as you describe, one still has set-theoretic difficulty to constructing an inverse functor: you either need a global choice or $C$ to be accessible. But this would be another question...

Comment: @BugsBunny Do you have as source for the existence of skeletons of accessible categories (under ZFC) that isn't Wikipedia? I ask because I think I have an argument that the existence of skeletons for accessible categories is also equivalent to global choice (in ZFC).

Comment: Actually I think my argument only establishes global choice for Ord-indexed families, but this is still non-trivial.

Comment: @James: If you have global choice for Ord-indexed families, you have global choice. Simply select a well-ordering for each $V_\alpha$, and then glue them together to well-order the universe. Now we can choose from whatever we want.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Ah right. This does need set choice though, right?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes, of course, that is what I had assumed, but what I found odd about the question is that it didn't make these critical aspects of the question explicit. I find the question very sloppy on this point.

Comment: The only conception of classes that makes sense in ZFC as opposed to GBC are the definable classes (allowing parameters). But in this case, the claim "every definable class category admits a skeleton" is not a statement that can be formalized directly in the language of set theory. Indeed, you cannot even formulate for a specific definable class category the statement that it admits a definable class skeleton, unless you can bound the logical complexity of the definition of the skeleton. This is just not a first-order statement in set theory.

Comment: In that sense, it doesn't make sense to consider the question purely in ZFC.

Comment: Nevertheless, if there is a definable global choice function (or global well order), then there is one of complexity $\Delta_2$, and this is how the global choice argument will work in ZFC---if every definable class has a skeleton, then we'll get a definable choice function, and from this a definable well order. Conversely, if there is a definable well order we get the skeletons as in the GBC context. But also, for the global well order it suffices that every weak skeleton can be given a skeleton, since the choice function must choose just from sets, not classes.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins: I think the average category theorist in the street isn't quite as careful about what "ZFC" means. But the OP should explain themselves in view of your comments.

Comment: Happy Hallowe'en!

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins blaming the OP for sloppiness in the technical aspects of the question in which they are not an expert is a bit harsh. I'm sure I've asked questions ahere I have professed my ignorance on set theoretical aspects for the very purpose of getting guidance and clarification.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins What is GBC? I have heard of NBG but not of GBC. I will correct the questions and will accept the answer, once everything is cleared in my head.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins  In a sense, I care about categories I work with having skeletons, like vector spaces (or something more complicated like an abelian category where ext-s are proper classes). I understand that you need to be able to talk about classes. This is NBG, is it not?

Comment: @JamesHanson I have heard it from someone before I have seen it on Wiki. Possibly, the person has seen it on Wiki too. My naive thought would be to choose a skeleton $S_1$ of the generator, then add all the filtered colimits of the elements of $S_1$ to $S$. This should be $S$. Where did I use the global choice?

Comment: GBC is an alternative acronym for Gödel-Bernays set theory, the same as NBG. The N is von Neumann, who formulated the principle Limitation of Size, which combines the global choice principle and replacement into one axiom (my view is that we lack separate intrinsic justification for LS, unlike global choice and replacement). I don't follow your remark about classes and NBG, since in the OP you focus on ZFC, which has no classes officially, only sets. One can implement definable classes, though, which is why I found the question flawed without clarifying exactly how you want to treat classes.

Comment: But let me apologize for my comment about sloppiness, which evidently came off harsher than I had intended. (That remark was mainly an explanation to Andrej of why I had asked about the notion of classes was meant, and it was not directed to the OP.)

Comment: Let me also add that in the ZFC context there is no axiom of global choice, since that is a second-order axiom, not expressible directly in the language of ZFC. But when one is using only definable classes, then the existence of a definable global choice function is equivalent in any model of ZFC to the axiom V=HOD(a) for some parameter a, which is first-order expressible. So most references in this thread to global choice should be using V=HOD(a) instead.

Comment: @BugsBunny Colimits, like everything defined by a universal property, are only define up to (unique) isomorphism. You need some amount of global choice to choose which particular realizations of the colimit end up in $S$. You can see this issue play out if you apply the argument in my answer to $\mathrm{Set}$.

Comment: If you have a uniform way of choosing filtered colimits (which you usually do in 'natural' categories), this isn't an issue, but this isn't stated on Wikipedia.

Comment: @BugsBunny Also, you may end up generating isomorphic objects in more than one way in terms of filtered colimits, at which point you need more global choice to choose which ones to keep in $S$. This issue isn't fixed by having canonical filtered colimits in general.

Comment: @James: Yes, you'd need AC for sets for this. You can see that by simply taking $V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ in a model of $\sf AC_{WO}$ where $\sf AC$ fails. But the question, as a whole, takes place in ZFC.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Right. I was just trying to get my own thinking straight. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment, but given the fact that there seems to be an incorrect statement on Wikipedia, I felt like it might be good to write some of these observations out more fully.

---

As per Joel David Hamkins' comments, we need to be a bit careful about what we mean by classes and quantifying over classes and such. Since you want to focus on $\mathsf{ZFC}$, the only reasonable notion of class is that of definable classes (i.e., classes of elements selected by some formula possibly with parameters). I'm going to think about for-all-exists statements regarding classes in a relatively constructive way as in if I say 'for all classes $X$, there is a class $Y$ such that...', what I mean is that there's an explicit procedure for producing a formula defining the class $Y$ given a formula for the class $X$ which works in any model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (although this procedure may in general involve finding new parameters). In particular, statements of this form can also be taken as an assumption, rather than a conclusion, and this assumption may only hold over certain models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. As Joel also pointed out, in principle things might get a bit hairy if there's no uniform bound on the complexity of the formula for $Y$ in terms of the formula for $X$, but I don't think that's really an issue here. I think these arguments would actually go through in $\mathsf{GBC}$, but I'm not sure.

I need a notion of equivalence of categories that is sensible without choice. I suspect the 'correct' notion involves [anafunctors](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/anafunctor), but I don't actually know enough category theory to be able to work with those. All I really want to say is that equivalence of categories is an equivalence relation (again, this is a relation we're defining on formulas over some fixed model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$) and if I have a functor $F : C \to D$ that is fully faithful and essentially surjective, then $C$ and $D$ are equivalent.

---

First, we have the fact that if you have skeletons for too many kinds of categories, you definitely get global choice. (Thanks to Asaf Karagila for pointing out how to finish this argument.) Here's a reasonably general form of the statement:

We'll say that a category $C$ *has a spine* if there is a definable sequence $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}}$ of pairwise distinct isomorphism classes of $C$. (Note that we don't really need to worry about the $A_\alpha$'s being proper classes by Scott's trick.)

> **Proposition 1.** If there is a category $C$ that has a spine such that any category $D$ equivalent to $C$ has a skeleton, then global choice holds.

*Proof.* Let $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}}$ be a spine of $C$. For each $\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}$, let $X_\alpha$ be the set of all well-orderings of $V_\alpha$ (which is non-empty by set choice). Define a new category $D$ whose objects are either

- $\langle B,0\rangle$ for some object $B \in C$ not in the given spine of $C$ or
- $\langle A_\alpha,1,x\rangle$ for $\alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}$ and $x \in X_\alpha$.

The morphisms are defined from the morphisms of $C$ in the obvious way (e.g., the morphisms from $\langle A_\alpha,1,x\rangle$ to $\langle A_\alpha,1,x'\rangle$ for $x\neq x'$ are just the morphisms of $A_\alpha$ into itself. Note that the obvious map from $D$ to $C$ is a fully faithful epimorphism of categories, so $D$ and $C$ are equivalent.

Let $S$ be a skeleton of $D$. Evidently we now have a choice function for the family $(X_\alpha)$ (by asking which elements of the form $\langle A_\alpha,1,x\rangle$ are in $S$). Finally, by Asaf's argument we can piece these together to get a global well-ordering and therefore global choice. $\square$

We get an immediate corollary which is that if any category equivalent to $\mathrm{Set}$ has a skeleton, then global choice holds. In particular, this makes me question [the statement on Wikipedia that in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ any accessible category has a skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)#Existence_and_uniqueness).

I actually cannot come up with an example of a large category that does not have a spine, so Proposition 1 already covers most of the categories one would probably want to think about.

---

Okay but what about spineless categories? Is there any hope that they might have skeletons (which I guess would necessarily be exoskeletons)? In order for a result like this to be relatively natural, one would hope that it would be preserved under passing to equivalent categories. My intuition, however, is that skeletons are just far too [evil](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352085/are-evil-properties-really-evil) for any kind of general (purely categorical) statement to not imply global choice. I don't have a proof of this yet, but I have a partial result, which I'll give here. Perhaps someone else can come in and complete the argument.

First we'll need the following fact.

> **Fact.** ($\mathsf{ZFC}$) There is a linearly ordered proper class $W$ with a definable surjection $f : W \to V$.

*Proof.* Let $W$ be the class of sets of ordinals that code a structure isomorphic to the $\in$-diagram of the transitive closure of some set (via the Gödel pairing function). The lexicographic ordering on sets of ordinals gives a definable linear order. For any $x \in W$, let $f(x)$ be the set coded by $x$. $\square$

> **Proposition 2.** Suppose that there is a large category $C$ such that any category equivalent to $C$ has a skeleton. Then there is a proper class $P$ with a definable linear order such that any $P$-indexed family of sets has a definable choice function.

*Proof.* Let $C'$ be the category whose objects are of the form $\langle B, x \rangle$ where $B$ is an object of $C$, $x \in W$, and $f(x) = B$. Define automorphisms in $C'$ in the same way as before. $C'$ clearly has a fully faithful epimorphism onto $C$ and so they are equivalent as categories. Let $S$ be a skeleton of $C'$. The definable linear order on $W$ now gives a definable linear order on the objects of $S$.

Now, let $\mathrm{ob}(S)$ be the class of objects of $S$. Let $(X_B)_{B \in \mathrm{ob}(S)}$ be an $\mathrm{ob}(S)$-indexed family of non-empty sets. We can now play the same game and define a category whose objects are of the form $\langle B,x\rangle$, where $B \in \mathrm{ob}(S)$ and $x \in X_B$. Taking a skeleton of this category gives the required choice function. $\square$

With a little bit of fiddling we can also make sure that the linear order is '$\mathrm{Ord}$-like' (i.e., has that each initial segment is a set), but I don't see what that buys us at the moment.

Comment: It is a fair bit more technical than the argument that I gave in this answer, but I believe I can also show this: If there is a sentence $\varphi$ in the (first-order) language of categories such that any category equivalent to a category satisfying $\varphi$ has a skeleton, then global choice holds.

Comment: Uhm, what's the language of categories, precisely? Wouldn't it be problematic if $\varphi$ could express the fact that the category has precisely one object and one morphism?

Comment: @AndrejBauer Ah yes I need to be more clear than that. I need to assume that $\varphi$ is consistent with having infinitely many pairwise non-isomorphic objects (and that the statement regarding skeletons holds even for class-sized categories). By the language of categories I mean the two-sorted language (objects and morphisms) where you have relations (or partial functions) encoding all of the normal structure of a category (identity morphisms, domain and codomain, and composition).

Comment: Basically the argument is that you can (in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without global choice) build a category satisfying $\varphi$ that has a spine (in the sense of my answer).

Comment: If $O$ and $M$ are the two sorts of objects and morphisms, consider the statement $\forall o \in O . \bot$. The only category satisfying this is empty, and so is any category equivalent to it, and also skeletal. (I just wanted to provide a simple example that shows something needs to be assumed about $\varphi$.)

Comment: If there is a dubious statement in Wikipedia, please consider adding a citation request to that statement.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Right, so to actually make the careful statement, what I believe I can prove is this: In $\mathsf{ZFC}$, if $\varphi$ is a sentence in the first-order language of categories such that there is a category $C$ satisfying $\varphi$ with infinitely many pairwise non-isomorphic objects and any set- or class-sized category equivalent to a category satisfying $\varphi$ has a skeleton, then global choice holds (i.e., $\exists a (\mathrm{V} = \mathrm{HOD}(a))$, as Joel is pointing out elsewhere). And actually, it can be more than a sentence. It can be any theory of bounded quantifier rank.

Comment: @colt_browning: In the good old times one could just delete non-sense from Wikipedia.